# NullPointerException because of a long click on a TextView

Tags: android

I found this weird error thanks to Crashlytics and it happened with a Samsung G386T. The Android app includes the new classes packages android.support.v7 to include the "toolbar" component. Unfortunately, the error is very "general" and it doesn't name the classes, in my app, where the error started.

An example of an custom activity declaration:

```
public class AccessAccountActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.access_acount_activity);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

}

Gradle (Android Studio):

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'`

[Error Trace]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1010)
   at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10153)
   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19434)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Post the code for the 'TextView'.

Comment: Post code of textview.

Comment: is that everything Crashalytics tells you?

Comment: It's the big problem. I don't know which the TextView is. Unfortunately, it was the complete report of Crashlytics.

Comment: I'm seeing the same crash and stack trace on specific Samsung devices: SM G260H, SM N9005, SM N910F, SM N910C. On Android 4.4.2 and 4.4.4. No idea what is causing it. No reference to any of my code. I'm guessing yet another Samsung bug. Have you had any luck tracking it down, @JesúsCastro?

Comment: @myanimal No, I haven't. It would be interesting to try with the new AppCompat v22.

Comment: this issue still exists in some Samsungs, any solution or  it from somebody?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must use return value for longClick  (TRUE)

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are doing some more action on textview..i faced similar issue and I found out that along with long press I was doing one more action(say showing dialog,etc) due to which this error was happening..try to avoid doing it..or put a timer.Please note that for me it was only happening on lollipop versions of Samsung reported by crashlytics.